# XPath regex for file extension

Tags: regex, xpath

```
<root>
    <url>
      <str>http://test.com/test.csv</str>
      <str>http://example.org/rsgis.html</str>
      <str>http://something.edu/thro.zip</str>
    </url>
</root>
```

Using Xpath can I find ONLY the file extensions (csv or html or zip) for the url's. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0? Earlier versions don't support regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/root/url/str/replace(tokenize(., '/')[last()], '.*\.', '')`. Or the tokenizing is not really needed, you could just remove everything including the latest dot `.` with `/root/url/str/replace(., '.*\.', '')`